# connection refused for jesque based application in cloud foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am trying to deploy `resque(i.e jesque java version)` based stand alone application in cloud foundry, i binded redis service while deploying the application.

I am using `STS` for all this process. But am getting exception like

```
 redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:134)
        at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:69)
        at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.sendCommand(Connection.java:79)
        at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.select(BinaryClient.java:148)
        at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.select(Jedis.java:328)
        at net.greghaines.jesque.TestUtils.createJedis(TestUtils.java:75)
        at net.greghaines.jesque.TestUtils.resetRedis(TestUtils.java:45)
        at com.accenture.creditcard.UseCreditCard.resetRedis(UseCreditCard.java:23)
        at com.accenture.creditcard.UseCreditCard.main(UseCreditCard.java:56)
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:129)
```

Answer (score 1):

When pushing app to cloud foundry, the CF provisioned data services have different configurations, e.g., username/password from your own configs. For Java standalone applications you have to first retrieve the connection information of the binded services from an environment viable provided by cloud foundry called "VCAP_SERVICES". You should find all the properties needed to set up the connection to cloud foundry provisioned redis service.

For other types of app like spring web app, there is a feature of CF called auto-reconfiguration which takes care of the connection set up automatically by certain programming convention. Here is the doc for your interest: http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/frameworks/java/spring/spring.html